# I can't push my rails app to heroku as I am getting error in gem eventmachine -v 1.0.3

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to push to heroku and I am getting the following error while compiling em.cpp

```
remote:        em.cpp: In member function `void EventMachine_t::_RunEpollOnce()'
:
remote:        em.cpp:574:37: error: `rb_thread_select' was not declared in this
 scope
remote:        EmSelect (0, NULL, NULL, NULL, &tv);
remote:        ^
remote:        em.cpp: In member function `int SelectData_t::_Select()':
remote:        em.cpp:827:67: error: `rb_thread_select' was not declared in this
 scope
remote:        return EmSelect (maxsocket+1, &fdreads, &fdwrites, &fderrors, &tv
);
remote:        ^
remote:        em.cpp: In member function `void EventMachine_t::_RunSelectOnce()
':
remote:        em.cpp:946:40: error: `rb_thread_select' was not declared in this
 scope
remote:        EmSelect (0, NULL, NULL, NULL, &tv);
remote:        ^
remote:        make: *** [em.o] Error 1
remote:
remote:        make failed, exit code 2
remote:
remote:        Gem files will remain installed in /tmp/build_3dd2419d1d67596ff83
72a3b46fb25f8/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/eventmachine-1.0.3 for inspection.
remote:        Results logged to /tmp/build_3dd2419d1d67596ff8372a3b46fb25f8/ven
dor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.2.0-static/eventmachine-1.0.3/ge
m_make.out
remote:        Installing tzinfo 1.2.2
remote:        Installing pg 0.18.1
remote:        An error occurred while installing eventmachine (1.0.3), and Bund
ler cannot
remote:        continue.
remote:        Make sure that `gem install eventmachine -v '1.0.3'` succeeds bef
ore bundling.
remote:  !
remote:  !     Failed to install gems via Bundler.
remote:  !
remote:
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Ruby app
remote:
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote:  !     Push rejected.
```

My app is written in rails 4.1.6 and postgres db.

Please help me sort this.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

EventMachine 1.0.3 has an issue with Ruby 2.2.x where it can't be compiled (https://github.com/eventmachine/eventmachine/issues/509). You'll need to upgrade to EventMachine 1.0.4 or above to be able to compile it using Ruby 2.2.x

Answer (score 0):

As was said with the previous answer, changing your Ruby version to 2.1.2 can also help you solve the incompatibility. Add this at the top of your Gemfile:

```
# Gemfile
ruby '2.1.2'
```